# Attaching listeners to some part of view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, view

I have a view in which there is a rectangle and few lines coming out from the edge of rectangle. I have set onClickListener for the entire view but is there any way in which I can set onClickListener for the individual parts(line) of a view?

My question is whether we can set listeners to a part of view in android?

My view class (DrawView.java)

```
    public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Rect r =new Rect(0, 0, 300, 40);



    public DrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);            
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, 1);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
        makeLinesinRange(0,40,300,40,300, 10, canvas,100);  // this will make 10 lines from edge of rectangle in downward side 
        requestLayout();
       }






    private void makeLinesinRange(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int size, int total_events, Canvas canvas,int width)
    {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        if(total_events<1)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(total_events==1)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(((x1+x2)/2), y1, (x1+x2)/2, y2+size, paint);

        }
        else if(total_events==2)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(((x1+x2)/3), y1, (x1+x2)/3, y2+size, paint);
            canvas.drawLine((2*(x1+x2)/3), y1, 2*(x1+x2)/3, y2+size, paint);


        }
        else
        {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        float kk=(x2-x1)/(total_events-1);
        for(int i=0;i<total_events;i++)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(x1+i*kk, y1, x1+i*kk, y2+size, paint);
        }
        }
    }


}
```

My activity that contains the drawview

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;


    public class DrawView extends View {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 40);
        float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;

        int width = 5;
        int height = 300;

        List<HashMap<String, RectF>> lines = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, RectF>>();

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, 1);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
            makeLinesinRange(10, canvas); // this will
                                            // make 10 lines
                                            // from edge of
                                            // rectangle in
                                            // downward side
            requestLayout();
        }

        private void makeLinesinRange(int total_events, Canvas canvas) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

            int x = 0;
            int y = 40;
            int range = r.width()/total_events;
            range= range + ((range*10)/100);

            for (int i = 0; i < total_events; i++) {
                RectF r = new RectF();
                r.set(x, y, x + width, y + height);
                Paint mPaint = new Paint();
                mPaint.setPathEffect(null);
                canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
                HashMap<String, RectF> item = new HashMap<String, RectF>();
                item.put("" + i, r);
                lines.add(item);
                x+=range;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                    RectF r = lines.get(i).get("" + i);

                    if (r.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + (i+1) + " line clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println((i+1) + " line clicked");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);




    }
}
```

Now my new code onDraw method is
        Rect r =new Rect(0, 0, 700, 40);

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        width=sf*700;

        canvas.save();

        makeLinesinRangetwo(10, canvas); // this will


         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
        canvas.scale(sf,1,100,200);
        requestLayout();
        canvas.restore();
        }
```

In this only lines are expanding on scaling but rectangle is not.

Comment: you are saying few lines coming out from the edge of rectangle...
(1). From where you are getting that text?
(2). depending on the above 1st question the answer can be said...?

Comment: Is your custom view then yes you can do that

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I have included my custom view file. Can you tell me how to do it.

Comment: @GVSharma I am taking this text from a custom view. Please see the above files

Comment: what is the value of mScaleFactor?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia 
mScaleFactor will take the value from my gesture event of pinch zoom.  
This value represents scaling factor of rectangle and rectangle is expanded by using this value. This value will lie between 0.1 to 5

Comment: I post the answer did you tried or not?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia
Very thank you for your time. I have tried but it is detecting lines after some try. I don't know why this is happening. 
Some time line is detected but sometime not

Comment: I have posted an activity that contains your class. Please see it why the lines are not detected every time

Comment: It is working perfectly with me.

Comment: click is put on gray lines.

Comment: I am clicking on gray lines only. Please try for some more cases. It is detecting sometime and not detecting sometime

Comment: @BirajZalavadia
Your code is not working when I am scaling around a pivot. Please see the last part in question. I have added my code.
Please help me in finding my bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Hope help you.

I have implement click event on your lines. Try this code.

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 40);
    float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;

    int width = 5;
    int height = 300;

    List<HashMap<String, RectF>> lines = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, RectF>>();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, 1);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
        makeLinesinRange(10, canvas); // this will
                                        // make 10 lines
                                        // from edge of
                                        // rectangle in
                                        // downward side
        requestLayout();
    }

    private void makeLinesinRange(int total_events, Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 40;
        int range = r.width()/total_events;
        range= range + ((range*10)/100);

        for (int i = 0; i < total_events; i++) {
            RectF r = new RectF();
            r.set(x, y, x + width, y + height);
            Paint mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setPathEffect(null);
            canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
            HashMap<String, RectF> item = new HashMap<String, RectF>();
            item.put("" + i, r);
            lines.add(item);
            x+=range;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                RectF r = lines.get(i).get("" + i);

                if (r.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + (i+1) + " line clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println((i+1) + " line clicked");
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks man.. I increases the width of rectangle and now its working fine.

Comment: Hey I stuck in one case. When I am scaling this view around some pivot, only lines are scaling but rectangle is not scaling.
This is I have done:
canvas.scale(mScaleFactor,1,pivotx,pivoty). this is only expanding the lines but not rectangle. Can you please tell me the work around for this.